# AWS lambda - Release /tmp storage after each execution

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have 4 lambda functions which will be invoked at same time (by SNS), the frequence of SNS's event is 5 minutes.
Each function process the large mount of data and images(~300MB) so I store them on `/tmp` folder (500MB limit).

At the beginning of  function, I wrote some code to the clean up `/tmp` folder, to make sure it's not out of memory (Because I've known that AWS lambda sometimes reuses previous container to improve performance).

I check it manually (create message and publish by SNS to 4 lambda functions), it worked fine.

But when it runs automatically (invoked each 5 minutes) the result is not as my expectation. The first execution is fine, but the next times after, 1 of 4 or even 4 lambda functions throw out the error related to "out of memory": "No space left on device", cannot load lib, ...

Previous, I use nodejs(4.3) it worked fine both case.

But I have to change to python for some reason, the main flow and the mount of created data is the same. But it's failed when run automatically.

I think that the issue came from the cache of previous container (reused container), I checked the `/tmp` after clean (`ls -alh /tmp`) there's no files but when check the storage (`df /tmp`) it show that used is 77%.

Any suggestion to make clean `/tmp` folder or work around solution is very appreciate. Thank!

Edited: Code I use to clean `/tmp` folder:

```
from subprocess import call
...
call('rm -rf /tmp/*', shell=True)
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to remove the files in `/tmp`?

Comment: I have added the code which I use to clean /tmp folder.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you solve your problem ? If so, could you please share your solution? Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is such a non-sense from AWS in a serverless service. The /tmp directory should be automatically cleaned after each execution I think.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on how to permanently delete /tmp or a folder inside /tmp on AWS lambda?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, lambda being a managed service; they do reuse the same underlying resource if the lambda is getting invoked repeatedly. This was a production problem we faced and fixed by deleting the /tmp. On a separate note AWS should mention this in their FAQs.

```
if os.path.exists(tmp_file_path):
        os.remove(tmp_file_path)
        print("Removed the file %s" % tmp_file_path)     
else:
    print("Sorry, file %s does not exist." % tmp_file_path)
```

Comment: They do mention it in the FAQ: "To improve performance, AWS Lambda may choose to retain an instance of your function and reuse it to serve a subsequent request, rather than creating a new copy. To learn more about how Lambda reuses function instances, visit our [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html). Your code should not assume that this will always happen."

Answer (score 3):

I tried to replicate this issue using [lambdash](https://github.com/alestic/lambdash), a great function to test out commands in your "dev" account. It allows you to run arbitrary UNIX commands in the Lambda environment.

I ran this command repeatedly, and did not see the issue appear.  Note: The commands are not actually in the deployed code so this test does not fully replicate the potential issue.

```
lambdash "echo Checking:;file /tmp/nullfile;rm -f /tmp/nullfile;df -h /tmp;dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=88888 >> /tmp/nullfile; echo ==========;df -h /tmp"
```

Comment: While not a solution per se, this is very useful information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Containers are often reused, but not concurrently. Clean up your temp directory when the function finishes and see if issue resolves.

Comment: I've tried it, I cleaned up /tmp at the beginning and the end in code.

Comment: I confirm this bug on node 10 containers today. I do remove all /tmp files (and dirs) but FREE disk space is shrinking after each invoke

Answer (score 1):

Warning `rm -rf /tmp/*` don't remove all files (hidden files or dir will not be deleted).

For a real clean of /tmp dir you should use : `rm -rf /tmp/..?* /tmp/.[!.]* /tmp/*`

For a complete explanation read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77313/66488